# R : problem with write.table and a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, write.table

I have a dataframe (mydataframe1) which looks like this :

```
      gene      expression         description
...     ...         ...              ...
112   G1246       2.4567      Heat shock protein
113   G1389      -1.7491      Heat regulation
114   G1467       0.1234      Cell component
...     ...          ...              ...
753   G1923       0.9435      Heat adaptative synthesis
...     ...          ...              ...
2843  G2123       1.4677      Immune response
```

I'm interested in genes having "heat" in their description, to get the concerned lines, I used the following script :

```
mydataframe2 <- mydataframe1[grep("heat_?", mydataframe1$description, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

I get a dataframe (mydataframe2) with the corresponding rows, but the row numbering is the same as in the original dataframe

```
      gene      expression         description
112   G1246       2.4567      Heat shock protein
113   G1389      -1.7491      Heat regulation
753   G1923       0.9435      Heat adaptative synthesis
```

I save this like this :

```
write.table(mydataframe2, "/my/path/heat_gene.csv", row.names=FALSE , col.names=TRUE, sep="\t", dec=".", quote=FALSE)
```

But when I open heat_gene.csv, I see that there are still all the rows of mydataframe1.

Do you know why?

Comment: (1) I cannot reproduce, when I look at `heat_gene.csv` it has just the three data rows in it. Perhaps you have it saved in multiple places and are reading in a version different from your recent saved file? (2) You name it `.csv` but it is clearly not comma-separated values, is that intentional?

Comment: More usable data, fyi: `mydataframe1 <- structure(list(gene = c("G1246", "G1389", "G1467", "G1923", "G2123"), expression = c("2.4567", "-1.7491", "0.1234", "0.9435", "1.4677"), description = c("Heat shock protein", "Heat regulation", "Cell component", "Heat adaptative synthesis", "Immune response")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))`. (It's more difficult to read in the print-render of a frame when there are spaces in values.)